# Meteor Flow router/Iron router with angular ui router

Tags: angularjs, meteor, iron-router, angular-meteor, flow-router

I am trying to add server side rendering with separate root html files to my angular-meteor project. But, as server side rendering is not possible in angular and iron router/flow router which supports server side rendering does not play with angular but with blaze.
Please help
How can I can implement server side routing and angular ui-routing ?

Answer (score 0):

**Iron-Router** does server and client side routing, however **Flow-Router** does not.

It is recommended to use `Picker` for server-side rendering with **Flow-Router**, and it's basically like an Express router, so it should work fine wit Angular-Router

`meteor add meteorhacks:picker`

https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/picker

https://github.com/meteorhacks/picker/

It supports middleware too.

Good luck

Comment: Can you please provide any link to any example or blog, with server side rendering of route html files which will work as base file for angular apps... or to render views in angular-meteor without blaze using flow-router or picker. I couldn't find anything on internet :/

Comment: this is not server-side rendering, it is server side routing. 
the Meteor tutorial explains how to use Angular. I answered about server side routing because I thought you needed something else, but I don't even think you need this.
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/templates

Comment: ps: I don't use Angular. Angular is cumbersome and slower than Blaze or React, plus v1.x is going to be obsolete soon with Angular 2 coming up, and it is not backward compatible, so I'm staying away from it until I see something better.